Help with sealing cypress 100 yr old cypress beam
I have a cypress beam that is at least 100 years old and I want to use it in a shower as an exposed beam for the door. Do I need to seal this beam first? I was thinking maybe a few coats of shellac and then some hard wax? If not then what would y’all recommend?

This question is similar to: What is the best finish for wood in a bathroom. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. We also have multiple other Q&As that mention bathrooms and wood finish that the search will bring up if you use it.
